# docker pull equivalent in kubectl

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl

[Docker](https://www.docker.com/) provides a way to run the container using `docker run`

Or just pull the container image using `docker pull`

Found a [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/docker-cli-to-kubectl/) showing mapping between docker commands and kubectl.

Can't find `docker pull` equivalent in this doc.

If there is no any such equivalent to `docker pull`, then is there any way to just pull an image using `kubectl` cli.

Comment: When you use the `kubectl create` or `kubectl apply` to create the deployment and pods, kubernetes will pull the images for you in the back. `kubectl run` also does this.

Answer (score 2):

`crictl pull <image name>`

Answer (score 1):

In short - no, there is not.

And why would there be? Kubernetes is an orchestration tool for Docker, it will automatically pull pods for you if it needs them, so there's really no need to have a command to pull containers manually.

Answer (score 1):

I think there isn't a `kubectl ...` equivalent and some of the reasons might be:

- they are not equivalent . When you `docker pull` an image, you are planning to use it afterwards on your docker host. When you `kubectl ...` a deployment, you want the platform to schedule everything. For example if you have many worker nodes and the replicas are going to be scheduled to only two of them, then the other nodes don't have to pull the image.
- `kubectl` is a tool that talks to the API server to control the cluster. It would be wrong to make it also responsible for container images (see, [Leaky Abstractions](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/11/11/the-law-of-leaky-abstractions/)) since you have available a lower level tool that talks to the Container Runtime Interface for that: [`crictl`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/crictl/).

  ```
  k8s-master:~$ crictl --help
  NAME:
     crictl - client for CRI

  USAGE:
     crictl [global options] command [command options] [arguments...]

  VERSION:
     v1.12.0

  COMMANDS:
       attach        Attach to a running container
       create        Create a new container
       exec          Run a command in a running container
       version       Display runtime version information
       images        List images
       inspect       Display the status of one or more containers
       inspecti      Return the status of one or more images
       inspectp      Display the status of one or more pods
       logs          Fetch the logs of a container
       port-forward  Forward local port to a pod
       ps            List containers
       pull          Pull an image from a registry
       ...
  ```

  pic from: [www.aquasec.com/wiki/display/containers/Kubernetes+Architecture+101](https://www.aquasec.com/wiki/display/containers/Kubernetes+Architecture+101)
  [image]
- what takes place with container run-times under the hood is complicated and keeps evolving. Think about this, people started creating Kubernetes clusters and the container engine used was Docker. Then Docker adopted `containerd` so we had Kubernetes on top of Docker on top of `containerd`, which caused problems like this:

  > Users won't see Kubernetes pulled images with the `docker images` command... And vice versa, Kubernetes won't see images created by `docker pull`, `docker load` or `docker build` commands...
  >
  > source / more details: [**Kubernetes Containerd Integration Goes GA**](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/05/24/kubernetes-containerd-integration-goes-ga/)

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to pull by kubernetes in cli.

Why?

Becuase when you run  `kubectl create -f template.yml`   it containe an image and it cjecked that the image is exist or not. If it does not exist it pull image automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You will not find equivalent of `docker pull` in Kubernetes because this command is related to images management. Explanation below.

One of `Docker` features is abbility to create `Images`. You can create your own image using `Dockerfile` (`docker build .`) or pull from [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=&type=image) which contains many pre-built images.

If you use `pull` command it will just download image, it will not deploy any container.

```
$ docker pull hello-world
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world

$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
hello-world         latest              fce289e99eb9        5 months ago        1.84kB

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

As you see, `$ docker pull` will only display download image. As Docker is also responsible for image management you can `pull` or `push` images to repository (DockerHub).

To create container in `Docker` you have to use `$ docker run`. This command will automatically download image and run container.

```
$ docker run --name mynginx -p 80:80 -d nginx
Unable to find image 'nginx:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/nginx
...

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
4abf804611a8        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   mynginx
```

In short:

`Create` adds a writeable container on top of your image and sets it up for running whatever command you specified in your CMD. The container ID is reported back but it’s not started.

`Start` will start any stopped containers. This includes freshly created containers.

`Run` is a combination of create and start. It creates the container and starts it.

Kubernetes is container-orchestration system so it is not responsible for creating or edit images. **That is why you will not find equivalent of `docker pull` (download only image).**

Commands like `kubectl apply -f <deployment>` with image inside YAML file or `kubectl run nginx --image=nginx` are based on images from DockerHub (more like `docker create`).

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a bit tricky, but it is possible to achieve similar to `docker pull` results using `kubectl`. You just need to know how to exit the containers with zero exit code.

The idea is to pull several images on all nodes in the Kubernetes cluster. 
For doing this you could create a [DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) which will try to create Pods on every applicable node in the cluster. To pull several images at once, just add several [initContainers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) to the DaemonSet template. `ImagePullPolicy` set to `IfNotPresent`, `restartPolicy` set to `Never`. Set `command` individually to each initContainer to make it exit successfully. You need something like `sh -c "exit 0"`, just ensure that container has `sh` binary inside, or use another possible command that usually gives you zero exit code: `<appname_binary> version` or `<appname_binary> --help`.

After applying that DaemonSet to the cluster, Kubernetes creates Pods from DaemonSet templates on each node and runs each initContainer in the Pod in order of presence. Before starting each container kubelet pulls the image required to run that container.

When you see that all DaemonSet Pods completed successfuly - you can be sure that on every node you have all images, required for running those containers.

You can play with [nodeAffinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/) or [taints/tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/) if you want to run the DaemonSet only on specific nodes.